# Count number of occurrences of a string in a cell range matching column and row headers

Tags: excel

I have the following two tables in MS Excel.

[image]

I want to count the number of occurrences of 'AB' in the rows of 'Adam' and in the columns of 'Feb' and place in P2 cell.

Index and Match commands used as follows returns 'AC'. What is the best way to solve this?

```
=INDEX($B$3:$L$12,MATCH($N$2,$A$3:$A$12,1),MATCH($P$1,$B$1:$L$1,1))
```

Here is the [file](https://spaces.hightail.com/receive/Zi6FNg2ogM).

Comment: Try with countifs(), if you had given data then I would have made an attempt.

Comment: @SolarMike, I tried, but could not solve yet. Updated question with the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the SUMPRODUCT Function, it does not require CTRL SHIFT ENTER, so just copy the formula from here and paste it in the cell P2 and Fill down and fill across.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($N$2=$A$3:$A$12)*($O2=$B$3:$L$12)*(P$1=$B$1:$L$1))
```

[image: SUMPRODUCT FUNCTION]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
=SUM(($B$3:$L$12=$O2)*($B$1:$L$1=$P$1)*($A$3:$A$12=$N$2))
```

may need array-entering pre Excel 365.

[image]

Comment: SUM(($B$3:$L$12=$O2)*($B$1:$L$1=P$1)*($A$3:$A$12=$N2)) would allow dragging for other names or months.

Comment: Tom's and @SolarMike's answers did not solve the problem yet. BTW, I use Excel 16.57 on Mac.

Comment: Have added screenshot to show it working on small amount of data

Comment: Entered the data and works for me, BTW using Macbook Pro, OS X 11.6.2 with Excel 16.54