# Output a list if month row and columns match

Tags: excel

I have a table with month as per below

[image: Excel Snapshot]

In another worksheet, a column will display a list (please refer to cell R2:R11 in the snapshot) of part number that matches the selected month and content (that contain partial text).

Very much appreciated to share with me the method. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. Actually, the table is simplified and I have 5 years records in the past and 50 part number. To me, it seems like array and not sure how if-else can output a filtered list.

Comment: See if this helps ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70912918/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-cell-range-matching-column-and-row

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt sharing. The post take Name column as one of the selection criteria and count the quantity; in my case, it is the output, and, in list after filtered. Hence, when I change the month, the output list (part name) will become longer or shorter breakdown list. Say if I select Dec-22, the list will change to PN007, PN008, PN010, PN011, PN013, PN014.

Comment: Do you have Excel 365?  This is a relatively simple application of the `FILTER` function.  What have you tried?

Comment: @James this should work for you `FILTER FUNCTION` if your are using O365 in cell R2 `=FILTER(A2:A15,LEFT(INDEX(C2:N15,,MATCH(P2,C1:N1,0)),2)=LEFT(Q2,2)) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you are using O365 then you use `FILTER FUNCTION` as shown below in the image

Formula used in cell R2 `=FILTER($A$2:$A$15,INDEX(($P$2=$C$1:$N$1)*(LEFT($Q$2,2)=LEFT($C$2:$N$15,2)),,MATCH($P$2,$C$1:$N$1,0)))`

[image: FILTER FUNCTION -- APPLICABLE TO EXCEL 2021 & O365 USERS]

Comment: I am using O365. THIS IS AWESOME, it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using in this way, i hope it should work for you as per your expected output, kindly refer image below, so here are two alternative ways

Formula used in cell R2 `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($C$2:$N$15)-ROW($C$2)+1)/(($P$2=$C$1:$N$1)*(LEFT($C$2:$N$15,2)=LEFT($Q$2,2))),ROW(A1))),"")`

Formula used in cell S2 `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$15,SMALL(IF((($P$2=$C$1:$N$1)*(LEFT($C$2:$N$15,2)=LEFT($Q$2,2))),ROW($C$2:$N$15)-ROW($C$2)+1),ROW(B1))),"")`

The second formula requires to confirm press CTRL SHIFT ENTER after entering formula if not using O365

[image]

Comment: May I ask, how does it works in Power Query?

Comment: Hi, do you have some reference on how to do it using power query?